# How to make size of image dynamic to the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an image that I want to be in the corner of the screen. What I am looking for is when someone resizes their page or zooms in or out the image will change relative to the size of the page.

This is what I am working with right now:

```
.flex_logo{
   padding: 2px;
   margin: 2px;
   border: solid;
   border-style: 5px;
   max-width: 20%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto\9;
}
```

It would be better if the answer was in CSS Flexbox as I am trying to learn it and better understand it.

Comment: the image by default resize when you simply specify % in width... so can you be more presice

Comment: Is .flex_logo's element a direct child of your body?

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero Yes